# MarkLogic directory-query with wildcard

Tags: wildcard, marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I want to search in MarkLogic with using `term-query` in direcories that meet the pattern:

```
/example/*/folder/
```

i.e.

```
/example/foo/folder/
/example/foo/bar/folder/
```

and so on...
I have something like this:

```
<search xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <query>
    <and-query>
      <directory-query>
        <uri>/example/*/folder/</uri>
        <depth>1</depth>
      </directory-query>
      <term-query>
        <text>some text</text>
      </term-query>
    </and-query>
  </query>
</search>
```

..but unfortunately `<directory-query>` seems not supporting wildcards in URI. Any idea how to use `<directory-query>` with wildcards?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`cts:uri-match()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:uri-match) instead, and then apply those URIs to a [`cts:document-query()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:document-query):

```
cts:document-query(cts:uri-match("/directory/*/folder/*"))
```

Comment: Coud you also provide snippet in JAVA Api?

Comment: cts:uri-match("/directory/*/folder/*" returns files and folders, how return only folders?

Comment: The example from Mads is no longer a `cts:directory-query()`. It is now a `cts:document-query()`.  The expansion into all documents that would match the wild-carded directory is already done. Therefore, needing to worry about directories is no longer in scope in the sample.