# Marklogic search for all files in pattern

Tags: java, marklogic, glob

I want to list all files (*.XML) in Marklogic database.
How to implement such functionality in MarkLogic JavaAPI?
Which works like:

```
cts:document-query(cts:uri-match("/directory/*/folder/*.xml"))
```

Related problem:
[MarkLogic directory-query with wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75856444/marklogic-directory-query-with-wildcard/75856708#75856708)

Answer (score 0):

`cts.documentQuery(cts.uriMatch("/directory/*/folder/*.xml"))`
Is this what you are expecting? This is the server side javascript (XQuery) equivalent of what you have asked.
If you want to pass a serialized query, you should first execute `cts:uri-match("/directory/*/folder/*.xml")` and then enclose the results into `cts:document-query` as shown below

```
<cts:document-query xmlns:cts="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">
  <cts:uri>/directory/2019/folder/1.xml</cts:uri>
  <cts:uri>/directory/2020/folder/2.xml</cts:uri>
  <cts:uri>/directory/2021/folder/3.xml</cts:uri>
</cts:document-query>
```

Best approach is to create a MarkLogic module server-side (in XQuery or JS) and invoke it from JAVA client API (by passing the uri-match string)

Comment: The following search-options in invalid in ML.
```
<cts:document-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
  <cts:uri-match>/directory/*/folder/*.xml</cts:uri-match>
</cts:document-query>
```
If you try using the above config, you will get this error - `XDMP-QUERYELEM: cts:query(<cts:document-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts" xmlns="">...</cts:document-query>) -- Query element contains unknown child: /x/cts:document-query/cts:uri-match`